# Nuxt3 deployment on vercel error 404 not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel, nuxtjs3

i am trying to deploy nuxt3 app to vercel .

I get the build success as well.

But once deployment is done getting 404 error page.

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
ssr: false,
target: 'static',
})
```

`package.json`

```
scripts": {
"dev": "nuxt dev",
"build": "nuxt build",
"start": "node .output/server/index.mjs",
"generate": "nuxt generate"
}
```

Build and deployment settings kept as it is.

Thanks!
Any help would be appreciated.

Attached image for the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

The error was coming from a mistakenly imported package `import anytime from 'anytime'`, removing it solved the issue.

---

You can run `npx serve .output/public` after `yarn generate` to see if it's working locally before trying to deploy anywhere.

Then for Vercel, you can either set the default value or use those.

[image]

Here is a working [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/n3-vercel/tree/main). Everything should be quite straightforward.

Comment: getting  this error while serving locally `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at entry-5a24b8b5.mjs:52:22446
    at entry-5a24b8b5.mjs:52:23429`

Comment: @SurajGupta it's an error specific to your code so. You will probably need to share your project.

Comment: But i am not using process anywhere in my project

Comment: @SurajGupta doesn't mean that it's not called down the road at some point.

Comment: Okay i will try to provide the minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Hi @kissu , i found the issue by mistake some package got imported because of that  getting that error `import anytime from 'anytime'`.

Anyway Thanks!!